# How does webservice maintain session when client is windows application C#?

Tags: c#, web-services

My method in my web service C#

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    int? Count = (int?)Session["Count"];
    if(Count == null) 
    {
        Count = 0;
    }

    Count++;

    Session["Count"] = Count;

   return "Hello World - Call Number : " + Count.ToString();
}
```

My window application client :

```
using WindowsFormsApplicationName.ServiceReference;
// ...
private NameServiceSoapClient WS = new NameServiceDataSoapClient();
//...

private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Can you write me how to use CookieContainer here ?
    string DataPOST = WS.HelloWorld();
    MessageBox.Show(DataPOST);
}
```

Can you write me how to use CookieContainer here if I don't use HttpWebrequest ?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: As you've pointed out yourself, you can use `CookieContainer`. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is how to use programmed !!!

Comment: That didn't help at all :) Explain what your question is, and show the relevant code. The code you've posted is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: What I wrote is my method in my web service ! But In my Windows application client, I wrote                                     using WindowsFormsApplicationName.ServiceReference;
...
private NameServiceSoapClient WS = new NameServiceDataSoapClient();
...
 
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Can you write me how to use CookieContainer here ?
string DataPOST = WS.HelloWorld();
MessageBox.Show(DataPOST);
}

Comment: Yes? And? How is that relevant to cookies, which are stored on client-side?

Comment: What I wrote is my method in my web service ! But In my Windows application client, I wrote                                     using WindowsFormsApplicationName.ServiceReference;                ...                                                           private NameServiceSoapClient WS = new NameServiceDataSoapClient(); ...                                                            private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {           // Can you write me how to use CookieContainer here ?           string DataPOST = WS.HelloWorld();           MessageBox.Show(DataPOST); }

Comment: Finally, we're getting there. Update your question with the code of the windows application client. That's the only relevant code to your question, the server code doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a web service reference, you have a `CookieContainer` property, just like in `HttpWebRequest`.

For a service reference (yeah, great naming...), you simply allow the use of cookies in the service binding in your `app.config`:

```
<system.ServiceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding allowCookies="true">
    </bindings>
</system.ServiceModel>
```

This is because service references aren't necessarily tied to HTTP, and cookies are a HTTP feature.

If you need to handle this in runtime, it's possible using `OperationContext`, but it's nasty and really quite an overkill for most scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use a CookieContainer when calling your WebMethod from your Windows App.

The HttpWebRequest object has a CookieContanier property that you need to set. Just create a CookieContainer object (only once per session) and assign it to all your requests that share the same session.

There is a sample in the official docs for CookieContainer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx). Just remember to use the same CookieContainer for all your requests.